# ugly URLs appear as 404 in GWT

Tags: permalinks

I use latest wordpress.
So, from WP side i make posts as always, i have set permalink structure: sitename.com/post name
htaccess has the rewrite rule set.
In google webmaster tools account the post urls appear the ugly ones: ?p=5211 etc.
Not all posts, just 30-40% from all posts i make - per day.
Could it be that google bot crawls the urls so fast that the post URL has not been able to change? when i click on the ugly urls they direct me to the right permalink structured post.

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no process of "change" to it really. Ugly URLs *always* work. Pretty permalinks just add a nice looking cover on top of them and internally turn the pretty version into an set of query arguments same as ugly version.

Most likely it is just taking a while for Google index to catch up.

To make it easier to scan your site you might want to use sitemap plugin and submit sitemap to Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rarst, i appreciate. I do have inserted sitmap_index.xml into google webmaster tools. Also, i use Yoast SEO plugin. I do hope this is temporary thing.. thanks